# Python - float object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry, I've seen many question related with this error but even with all this information I can't solve it.

I have a dataframe `df` with a column named `int_rate`. The column's type is `O`. It keeps the percentages, so each line is like: `10.95 %` I need to remove the `%` sign to transform then the column in `int`. I've tried with the following code:

```py
df['int_rate']=df['int_rate'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.

The first thing I don't understand is why float object if my column type is not float, and if so, how can I get rid of `%` sign?

Comment: if I am not mistaken the error you are getting is from the lambda expression and not the data frame. you are doing float[:-1] and float is not subscriptable. please provide a data sample.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the dataframe? and did you check dtypes of the columns?

Comment: It very well may be that your data frame contains floats but your display options for that data frame is to display percentages. Therefor you see a string `10.95%` that is set with `pd.options.display.float_format` BUT your data is actually a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your data contains some `NaN` values, since `NaN` are considered as `float` type in Pandas.

You can do a `df.info()` and look into the `Non-Null Count` to check whether the count for column `int_rate` corresponds to the existence of any `NaN` value.

If there is any `NaN` value, you can bypass the error by applying your code only to those non `NaN` entries, as follows:

```
df['int_rate'] = df.loc[df['int_rate'].notna(), 'int_rate'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
```

Here, we filtered to process only those rows with the boolean mask: `df['int_rate'].notna()` to exclude those `NaN` entries.

Comment: @CristinaDominguezFernandez Please consider also to upvote the solution if you like it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have 'object' column, so it could be a mix of various types.
Cast to string, then drop last symbol, or better replace percents as shivam suggested

```
df['int_rate']=df['int_rate'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:-1]  if str(x).endswith('%') else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, not all lines are of the form 'nnn.mm %', some are float ... Could you try this?

```
df['int_rate']=df['int_rate'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else float(x[:-1]))
```