# 'float' object is not subscriptable - not sure why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code. I am trying to select the 4th (index) item from a list at a given index location of the dataframe 'df'.

```
trialoutcomes = []

for j in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    for i in range(5,len(df)):
        trialoutcome = df.loc[i,j]
        trialoutcomes.append(trialoutcome[4])
```

However, I keep getting the error: ''float' object is not subscriptable', although I am not sure as to why.

When I take the code out of the loop below and enter the following code, I get the output I want, indicating a 'fullMiss' trial.

```
easy = df.loc[5,0]
print(easy[4])

fullMiss
```

However, in the context of the loop above this does not work.

When I enter:

```
df.loc[5,0]
```

This prints:

```
['trial', '2:7|2:8|4:1|4:2|8:3|8:4|', '4:7', '4:7', 'fullMiss', '5.828', '11', '37', '66']
```

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

The first 10 rows of the 'df' dataframe looks something like this:

```
                  0   ...                                                 77
5   [trial, 2:7|2:8|4:1|4:2|8:3|8:4|, 4:7, 4:7, fu...  ...  [trial, 7:4|7:5|2:2|3:2|2:7|2:8|, 4:3, 3:4, fu...
6   [trial, 2:3|3:3|7:6|8:6|3:7|3:8|, 2:7, 2:7, ne...  ...  [trial, 4:8|5:8|7:3|8:3|2:2|3:2|, 6:2, 6:2, ne...
7   [trial, 3:6|4:6|1:1|1:2|5:2|6:2|, 3:7, 4:6, hi...  ...  [trial, 5:5|5:6|3:1|4:1|1:6|1:7|, 6:7, 7:8, fu...
8   [trial, 8:5|8:6|1:7|1:8|7:1|8:1|, 2:2, 2:1, fu...  ...  [trial, 3:3|4:3|2:7|2:8|6:7|7:7|, 4:6, 3:6, ne...
9   [trial, 5:8|6:8|4:3|5:3|9:2|9:3|, 5:3, 5:3, hi...  ...  [trial, 7:2|7:3|1:4|1:5|5:7|6:7|, 3:4, 4:5, fu...
10  [trial, 1:5|2:5|6:2|7:2|8:7|9:7|, 2:5, 1:6, ne...  ...  [trial, 7:2|7:3|1:1|2:1|5:7|6:7|, 5:8, 5:9, fu...
11  [trial, 2:2|2:3|4:7|5:7|8:2|8:3|, 4:2, 5:3, fu...  ...  [trial, 1:3|2:3|5:8|5:9|9:2|9:3|, 5:6, 4:5, fu...
12  [trial, 2:2|2:3|5:9|6:9|8:2|8:3|, 6:5, 7:6, fu...  ...  [trial, 2:3|2:4|7:4|7:5|8:9|9:9|, 6:8, 6:9, fu...
13  [trial, 2:4|3:4|8:8|9:8|7:2|8:2|, 8:8, 8:9, ne...  ...  [trial, 2:2|3:2|7:7|7:8|7:3|8:3|, 4:5, 4:5, fu...
14  [trial, 7:5|8:5|3:4|3:5|6:9|7:9|, 7:4, 7:3, fu...  ...  [trial, 6:3|6:4|3:9|4:9|2:2|2:3|, 4:8, 4:9, hi...
```

Comment: Can you print out *i* and *j* to see if any particular cell in the data frame has a list which doesn't fit your expectation?

Comment: can you add to the question **df.loc[1,2]** ?

Comment: sory, your index starting to 5. Use this: `df.loc[5,0]`

Comment: I would have been surprised if `float` objects *were* subscriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your data contain nans:

```
a=['trial', '2:7|2:8|4:1|4:2|8:3|8:4|', '4:7', '4:7', 'fullMiss', '5.828', '11', '37', '66']

print(a[4]) #fullMiss

a=np.nan
print(a[4]) #TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

you can drop nans or you can add a control in loop:

```
for j in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    for i in range(5,len(df)):
        trialoutcome = df.loc[i,j]
        trialoutcomes.append(trialoutcome[4] if type(trialoutcome) ==list else None)
```

Comment: If it's okay for you to drop the rows, I suggest you drop the rows containing nan. because there will be as many None values ​​as nan in the list named trialoutcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the error doesn't happen on 5,0.  From what I can tell, you might be overdrawing your index - range(0, len(df.columns)) would end with an index beyond your last column index, and should instead be range(0, len(df.columns) - 1), I think?  Same for len(df).  If that all is hogwash, it might help to do print(i,j) when you actually run, to see where it's stumbling.  Perhaps you'll find a 'float'.

Comment: There are some 'NaN' values - would this affect it?          
30  [trial, 2:5|3:5|8:2|9:2|8:8|9:8|, 2:4, 3:5, hi...  ...  [trial, 3:2|4:2|5:6|5:7|9:5|9:6|, 7:4, 8:4, ne...
31                                                NaN  ...  [trial, 5:7|5:8|1:4|1:5|7:1|7:2|, 7:4, 7:4, fu...
32                                                NaN  ...  [trial, 3:6|3:7|7:6|8:6|7:2|8:2|, 4:3, 5:2, fu...
33                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN

Comment: Absolutely.  There are precedents for the exact same thing elsewhere; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67492485/python-float-object-is-not-subscriptable seems like it would have the answer to that issue.